# Drawing the Bratteli diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

could any one help me to draw this diagram
[image: Bratteli diagram]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to draw the Young diagrams is probably using a `pic` (see chapter 18 of the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual). The idea of the `pic` is that you loop over a comma separated list of the parts of the partition, and then loop over the columns in each row, to draw one node at a time:

```
\tikzset{
  pics/diagram/.style={
    code = {
       \foreach \row [count=\r] in {#1} {
           \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
               \draw[thick](\col,-\r) rectangle ++(-1,1);
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Using this you can draw a Young diagram of shape `(5,4,2,2,1)` with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pic at (0,0} {diagram={5,4,2,2,1}};
\begin{tikzpictire
```

Unfortunately, it is slightly painful to use this for drawing Bratteli diagrams because `pics` have no idea how big they are so it becomes necessary to painstakingly place all of the edges in the Bratteli diagram. To get around this I have covered the Young diagram with an appropriately sized rectangular node and, for good measure, given it an automatic label of the form `i-mu`, where `i` is the 'level' of the diagram and `mu` is the partition. For example, the partition `(2)` at level `4` is given the label `4-2` and the partition `(2,1)` at level `3` is given `3-21`. This makes it possible to draw the edges in the Bratteli diagram using code like:

```
\draw(0-0)--(1-1)--(2-0)--(3-1)--(4-0);
```

which is the series of edges going down the left hand side of the image below. The code below only draws some of the edges in the Bratteli diagram. The rest are left as an exercise. Here is the output:

[image]

Here is the full code, with contains comments to explain what is going on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  pics/diagram/.style 2 args={% #1=i, #2=partition as comma separated list
    code = {
      \def\diagramlabel{}% we build the automatic label i-mu 
      \begin{scope}[scale=0.5, yshift=-5mm]
         \foreach \row [count=\r] in {#2} {
             % record \lastrow and \lastcol to put a rectangular node
             % around the Young diagam
             \ifnum\r=1
               \pgfmathparse{0.5*(\row+1)}
               \xdef\lastcol{\pgfmathresult}
             \fi
             \pgfmathparse{0.5*(\r+1)}
             \xdef\lastrow{\pgfmathresult}
             \xdef\diagramlabel{\diagramlabel\row}
             \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
                 % draw a cell in the Young diagram
                 \draw[thick](\col,-\r)rectangle++(-1,1);
             }
         }
         % the rectangular node around the diagram with label i-mu
         % the node is an (n+1)x(n+1) square shifted NW by 0.5 units
         \node[rectangle, anchor=north west,
              minimum height=\lastrow cm, minimum width=\lastcol cm]
              (#1-\diagramlabel) at (-0.5,0.5){};
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5]
      % for-loop to create the i=#labels and start each row of the
      % Bratteli diagram. Here \row runs over a list of row heights
      % so you can change this list to fine-tune the height of each row
      \foreach \row [count=\c (from 0)] in {0,1,3,5,7} {
        \node(\c) at (0,-\row) {$i=\c$};
        \node[right=of \c] (\c-0) {\ifodd\c\relax\else$\emptyset$\fi};
      }
      % now use the positioning library to place the Young diagrams to
      % the right of the i=# label
      % i=1
      \pic[right=of 1-0.north east] {diagram=1{1}};
      % i=2
      \pic[right=of 2-0.north east] {diagram=2{2}};
      \pic[right=of 2-2.north east] {diagram=2{1,1}};
      % i=3
      \pic[right=of 3-0.north east]  {diagram=3{1}};
      \pic[right=of 3-1.north east]  {diagram=3{3}};
      \pic[right=of 3-3.north east]  {diagram=3{2,1}};
      \pic[right=of 3-21.north east] {diagram=3{1,1,1}};
      % i=4
      \pic[right=of 4-0.north east]  {diagram=4{2}};
      \pic[right=of 4-2.north east]  {diagram=4{1,1}};
      \pic[right=of 4-11.north east] {diagram=4{4}};
      \pic[right=of 4-4.north east]  {diagram=4{3,1}};
      \pic[right=of 4-31.north east] {diagram=4{2,2}};
      \pic[right=of 4-22.north east] {diagram=4{2,1,1}};
      \pic[right=of 4-211.north east]{diagram=4{1,1,1,1}};

      % Finally it remains to draw all of the edges...and here I got
      % bored so I have only drawn some of them. It should be easy to
      % add the rest
      \draw(0-0)--(1-1)--(2-0)--(3-1)--(4-0);
      \draw(1-1)--(2-2)--(3-1);
      \draw(1-1)--(2-11)--(3-1);
      \draw(1-1)--(2-2)--(3-1);
      \draw(1-1)--(2-11)--(3-1)--(4-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, Very nice !

Comment: There are LaTeX packages for drawing Young tableaux. Such packages might save time, and be more flexible.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay There certainly are packages for drawing **Young diagrams**, such as [ytableau](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau). However, the main problem here is *not* drawing the diagrams, which is easy. Instead, the problem is to draw the Bratteli diagram with the Young diagrams as vertices. As far as I am aware, none of these packages help with the Bratteli diagram. As a representation theorist, I'd be very happy to see another solution, so if you have one please post it.